# Can't call methods from other views in AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android-studio

So I got two views that are both in the same activity. I'm getting view1 in view2 with `uiView = findViewById(R.id.uiSurfaceView);` I then cannot, however, call a public method defined in uiView...

I'm fairly new to AndroidStudio and all I found here is about different classes, not views.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the type of your uiView variable? It does not look like you have cast the results of the findViewById method to a specific view type that you have defined. You will need to cast this to the correct type.

Comment: The type was the issue, thank you very much for this stupid mistake! I used the base type not the self made new type... Oh wow
I'd accept this answer if it wasn't for the fact that not even 5mins have passed.

Comment: As long as uiView is the right type, there is no need to cast the result of calling this method, as it's generic.